# Unauthorized access, conekta OXXO pay payment gateway

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I am trying to implement OXXO pay payment gateway for PHP but getting the **"Unauthorized access, please check the permissions of your key for this call.** error after enter the dummy card details.

step using

**Step 1: include the JS in the PHP**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://conektaapi.s3.amazonaws.com/v0.3.0/js/conekta.js"></script>
```

STEP 2 : script for payment

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Conekta Public Key
    Conekta.setPublishableKey("key_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");
    // ...
    jQuery(function ($) {


        var conektaSuccessResponseHandler;
        conektaSuccessResponseHandler = function (token) {
            console.log(Conekta,"toekn",token.id);
            //return false;
            var $form;
            $form = $("#card-form");
            /* Inserta el token_id en la forma para que se envíe al servidor */
            $form.append($("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"conektaTokenId\" />").val(token.id));
            var card_number = $form.find('#tarjeta').val();
            var last_number = card_number.slice(card_number.length - 4);
            $form.append($("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"cardt\" />").val(last_number));
            $form.append($("<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"card_brand\" />").val(Conekta.card.getBrand(card_number)));

            /* and submit */
            $form.get(0).submit();
        };

        conektaErrorResponseHandler = function (token) {
            console.log(token);

            jQuery(".card-errors").html(token.message);
        };

        $("#card-form").submit(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var $form;
            $form = $(this);

            /* Previene hacer submit más de una vez */
            $form.find("button").prop("disabled", true);
            Conekta.token.create($form, conektaSuccessResponseHandler, conektaErrorResponseHandler);
            /* Previene que la información de la forma sea enviada al servidor */
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any suggestion why getting the error with payment gateway #conekta #OXXO.need help.